# How can I type a single quote on the Raspberry Pi that doesn't cause syntax errors in Python?

Tags: python, character-encoding, keyboard, raspberry-pi

I have a Logitech 360 keyboard, with which I am trying to code Python on the Raspberry Pi B.  The apostrophe key produces a slanted quote, instead of the 'vertical' single quote, and this causes syntax errors in code (the same code runs perfectly when I paste in a snippet from the browser, which is the only way I can find to produce the correct flavor of apostrophe).

The syntax error is "Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file '---' on line X, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details."  The webpage suggests declaring a character encoding at the beginning of the script, but it didn't work for me, and in any case, I would rather not have to have it at the beginning of every script - I just want the keyboard to produce the correct character to begin with.  I have fiddled with the keyboard config international settings; nothing works.  It's driving me nuts.

Comment: What operating system do you have installed on the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I have a hard time believing that a keyboard would be hard-coded to only produce smart quotes. What kind of quotes does the keyboard produce when you type `'` in an editor like Notepad? What is the exact program where you're entering your code and seeing only smart quotes?

Comment: I have the Raspian OS from the NOOBS install package, and I've tried typing the quotes in IDLE, another IDE called Ninja, the browser, and they look the same everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use "\xc2" as a quote character without redefining the quote character in python source grammar(really your problems extend beyond even this) and recompiling python ....

you probably can change what character your logitech uses as a quote

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your Internationalisation Options by running

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Choose Option 4 - `Internationalization Options`  
and then Option I3 - `Change Keyboard Layout`  
Go through and check your settings and then try your keyboard again.